# Access to redshift super column with key from another column

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is it possible to access to redshift super column, with key from another column?

For example I have two column - one of them is super type, another is key for super column.

```sql
with temp as (select json_parse('{"aaa":{"1":2}}') as super_field,
                     'aaa'::text                   as super_key)
select super_field,
       super_key,
       json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(super_field), super_key) as extracted_text,
       --super_field.{super_key} Not working
from temp;
```

I found, that I can access to them via json_serialize + json_extract_path_text.
But maybe it is possible to do it in super field?

Comment: Using `json_extract_path_text` seems to be the only way I could identify to dynamically query a `SUPER` column when you don't have a static key you can use. This is a lot easier in PostgreSQL with the arrow notation which doesn't require a hard coded string. I'd really like to know the answer to this as what I want to extract is nested and doing something like `json_parse(json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(super_field), ...)))` breaks if you exceed `VARCHAR(MAX)` even though redshift supports up to 16MB in `SUPER` at this point. Also seems a lot less efficient.